# if IE only works for stylesheets?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

So I am forced to use conditional style for IEs via the [if IE] comment. I have been trying to fit it in my code but I found some inconsistency that I cant explain.

If I use it like this

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
    #SomeName {
        width: 100em;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

it will just not work.

However, if I put the style in a css sheet and add a link to it, it works.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../sheetName.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Is there a way for me to put the style inside the [if IE] tags rather than linking it through the  tag? it just looks wrong.

Thank in adavance

Comment: I wouldn't know about that. But what's the problem with linking to a different stylesheet? You do know this is actually preferrable right?

Comment: Works for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/y3kDu/. But, I would recommend using an IE-only stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with your code.

Make sure that `#SomeName` is as such in the html (*beacuse css rules are case-sensitive*), and make sure that you include your code after the normal css include (*to avoid having the rule overriden by what is in the normal css*)

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet should work just fine if you are using the correct CSS selector.  Make sure you are using the exact selector you need to adjust.  However the selector is being used in your normal stylesheet, just copy and paste it into the conditional tag and change whatever you need to change in regards to width or whatever.